# Problema al modificar las propiedades de otro objeto

Tags: java

Muy buenas, presento aqui mi problema para ver si puedo encontrarle solucion, llevo un rato intentando arreglarlo pero no encuentro la solución.
Explico:

Tengo una clase llamada Jarra, esta contiene 2 propiedades llamadas:

```java
public class Jarra {

    private int capacidad;

    private int contenido;
```

Luego inicializo la propiedad capacidad con un constructor sobrecargado:

```java
public Jarra(int capacidad) {

    if (capacidad <= 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("La capacidad no puede ser menor o igual a 0");
    }

    this.capacidad = capacidad;
}

public Jarra() {
    this.capacidad = 2;
}
```

Luego tengo otro metodo sobrecargado que llena la jarra:

```java
/**
  * Lleno el contenido de mi objeto al maximo de su capacidad definida previamente en el constructor
*/
public void llena() {
    this.contenido = this.capacidad;
}

/**
  * Lleno el contenido de mi objeto con el numero pasado por parametro
*/
public void llena(int cantidad) {

    if (cantidad > this.capacidad) {
        throw new RuntimeException("El contenido a llenar sobrepasa la capacidad de la jarra");
    }

    this.contenido = cantidad;
}

/**
    Llena el contenido de la jarra actual (receptora) con el contenido de la jarra
    que se recibe como parámetro (emisora), bien hasta que la jarra receptora quede llena o
    hasta que la jarra emisora se vacíe por completo
  * @param otraJarra
*/
public void llena(Jarra otraJarra) {

        if (this == otraJarra) {
            throw new RuntimeException("La contenido para llenar la jarra no puede provenis de esa misma jarra");
        }

        do {
            otraJarra.contenido--;
            this.contenido++;
        } while(otraJarra.contenido != this.capacidad || this.contenido == 0);
    }
```

Luego en otra clase de testeo instancio 2 objetos de la clase jarra:

```java
import paquete51.Jarra.Jarra;

public class TestJarraa {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Jarra jarraA = new Jarra(7);
        Jarra jarraB = new Jarra(4);

        // lleno al tope de su capacidad el primer objeto de jarra
        jarraA.llena();

        jarraB.llena(jarraA);

        System.out.println(jarraA.toString());
        System.out.println(jarraB.toString());
    }
}
```

Sin enmbargo el objeto jarraB no es llenado como yo espero:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me resta 1 litro menos y me suba 1 litro menos.

¿Como podría solucionar esto?. Gracias de antemano :D

Comment: En el comentario del método `llena()` indicas esto: *"bien hasta que la jarra receptora quede llena o hasta que la jarra emisora se vacíe por completo"* sin embargo en las condiciones del bucle veo esto: `otraJarra.contenido != this.capacidad || this.contenido == 0`, lo cual se traduce como `mientras otraJarra.contenido DISTINTO de la capacidad de esta jarra O el contenido de esta jarra sea 0`... no veo que sean las mismas condiciones. Ese while está mal formulado, para empezar porque no tienes en cuenta los litros que tenga la otra jarra en ningún momento, podrían ir a negativo sin problema.

Comment: La lógica de ese while debería comprobar `otraJarra.contenido > 0` para empezar, no  le veo mucho sentido al or de `this.contenido == 0`... qué importa que esté a cero la jarra actual, si la otra no tiene líquido dentro? Además, deberías comprobar `this.contenido <= this.capacidad` para no llenarla más de lo que puede. Y no debería ser un `or`, si no un `and`! Ambas condiciones son de obligatorio cumplimiento pues una jarra vacía no puede llenar nada, y una jarra llena no necesita más líquido. Es decir, quedaría `while(otraJarra.contenido > 0 && this.contenido <= this.capacidad)`